How to delete or remove a `crypto.subtle.importKey` key?
The MDN docs on importKey don't seem to provide a way to remove or delete a key once it is no longer needed. Since the function name includes the term "import", which may suggest some degree of permanence, is explicit action needed to delete the key? Will the key get garbage collected once it goes out of scope?

Have a look at How do you destroy keys with Subtle's cryptography API?.

Thanks, I've marked mine as a dupe
